# zf2 Why after press button Submit element password was cleared? How to avoid this?

Tags: zend-framework2

**Why after press button Submit element password was cleared? How to avoid this?**
Other elements memorize the entered values.

Answer (score 2):

this is by design for security reasons. password fields value gets reset in case of a form error .

Comment: +1 for understanding the question. And zfc-user has a base form with a password field. If you want to change it's behavior you could extend the Base.php Form from zfc-user.